# Scanf with NameSurname into two separate strings

Tags: c, string, scanf

I have a string to be read that is `AaaaBbbb` and I want it to be assigned into two separate strings as `Aaaa` and `Bbbb`.
In fact I have to read a SurnameName, with no spaces and have it in the two separate strings.

My goal is to separate the Surname to further process it.
I have not to check for unexpected cases and there is nothing else to check, just a list of SurnameName.

I can't manage to do that in a "simple" way.

My best attempt was

```
char str1[20], str2[20], str3[20]; 
fscanf(hl_inp, "%1c%[^A-Z]%s", str1, str2, str3);
```

but I would like to avoid any reassembling process, here with `str1` and `str2`.

Any idea to do that directly, or any better that my attempt?

EDIT: Complete reprashing, lets try a last time.

I have a string. It is all lower case chars with two and only two Upper case characters. The string can be 20 chars max.

The two upper case characters follow these rules:

- They are not consecutive.
- None of them can be the last character.
- One of them is always the first character.

This is best attempt:

```
char name[] = "WillisBruce";
    char str1[20], str2[20], str3[20];
    sscanf(name, "%1s%[^A-Z]%s", str1, str2, str3);

    strcat(str1, str2);

    printf("Name: %s, Surname: %s", str3, str1);
```

The string is "WillisBruce" in the example.
But it could be "CareyMariah", "JonhElton" as well as "ObamaBarak".

It could be not "McDonaldDonald", according to the rules.

I have not to check for the rules, I can have them as granted.

My example did the job I want, but I would like to know if I can avoid any kind of reassembling.

Comment: If you want to separate `AaaaBbbb` to `Aaaa` and `Bbbb`, just like this: `"%4[A-Za-z]%4[A-Za-z]", str1, str2`.

Comment: What is `name`? Is is the first 4 characters? Is is anything you find until you hit the next upper case letter? What about a middle name? Does it belong to `name`? Without telling us the rules for splitting, we cannot tell you how to implement them. BTW: You have both `NameSurname` and `SurnameName`

Comment: Isn't it acceptable to read `AaaaBbbb` in one string and split it later?

Comment: Hint: I would save myself the trouble of using `fscanf` and just use `fgets` or maybe `fscanf(..., "%30s", ...)` and write the 3-4 lines of code that splits the string myself. This also allows you easily to deal with unexpected input.

Comment: If you can assume that the input format respects the requirements you've described and given the fact that  `scanf` is pretty limited, I don't think you can make it any shorter and your code looks perfectly fine to me. However your usage of scanf looks quite "hacky" as you try to use scanf for something is is not really designed for.

Comment: Thanks @Jabberwocky. Its essentially what Im asking for. If it exits a magic format specifier that do the job reading the input in two separate strings that Im unable to reckon or if I have necessarily do some further job, as strcat or whatever. If there was a space between name and surname I could do it easily. Im asking if I can do something similar in this case.

Comment: BTW the format string in your first piece of code is significantly different from the one in the second one. `"%1c%...` (wrong) vs. `"%1s%...` (correct).

Comment: Yes you are right. I discovered  and corrected it trying the snippet to post here in the edit.

Comment: What about using: `fscanf(hl_inp, "%1c%[^A-Z]%s", &str1[0], &str1[1], str3);` — using your first format string.  It places the single character in `str1[0]` and the rest in `str1[1]` onwards, so there's no reassembly required.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler this is brilliant! Please make it as a reply so I can credit you the solution, if you want. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>*Transferring a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78120205/scanf-with-namesurname-into-two-separate-strings?noredirect=1#comment137728866_78120205) into an answer*</sup>

What about using:

```
fscanf(hl_inp, "%1c%[^A-Z]%s", &str1[0], &str1[1], str3);
```

This uses your first format string. It places the single character in `str1[0]` and the rest of the first name in `str1[1]` onwards, so there's no reassembly required.

You should protect against buffer overflows too (see also [How to prevent `scanf()` causing a buffer overflow in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1621394/15168)):

```
fscanf(hl_inp, "%1c%18[^A-Z]%s", &str1[0], &str1[1], str3);
```

You will run into problems with names like "McDonaldIain".  However, such devious issues are probably beyond the scope of the exercise.